# CDI + JPA + EJB + JTA + JSF --JBoss-Kitchen Example with PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, jboss, jboss7.x, cdi

I am trying to learn the new technologies `CDI + JPA + EJB + JTA + JSF` so, i have downloaded the sample project from `JBoss-Community`--> jboss-as-kitchensink(from JBoss in my Eclipse juno).

I am Trying to connect the `kitchen` with my **PostgreSQL** database:
My database name is : `sampledb`

My **Table(Member)** Structure is : **Database name** :`QUICKSTART_DATABASENAME`

```
CREATE TABLE member
(
  id integer, 
  name text,
  email text,
  phone_number numeric
);
```

I have edited this files in my kitchen Project :

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
     <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
           <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I Added the Dependency in **pom.xml**:

```
<!-- PostgreSQL Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

But i'm getting error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.554s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Sep 21 14:01:48 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/175M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project jboss-as-kitchensink: Deployment f
ailed and was rolled back. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
C:\Users\mypc\java\workspace\jboss-as-kitchensink>
```

What should i do so that i can run this application with my database to insert the data.

Do i need to change any code in `.java` files or any `.xml` file to make it work?

**EDITED after Comments:** By [Following this link](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/#optional_components),I have configured my PostgreSQL into JBoss manually 
by setting up the standalone-full.xml file of JBoss..

```
    ----///----    <datasources>
                        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                            <driver>h2</driver>
                            <security>
                                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                                <password>sa</password>
                            </security>
                        </datasource>

                        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS" pool-name="PostgreSQLpool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                            <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/QUICKSTART_DATABASENAME</connection-url>
                            <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                            <security>
                                <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                                <password>postgres</password>
                            </security>
                        </datasource>
                        <drivers>
                            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                            </driver>

                            <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                                <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                            </driver>
                        </drivers>
                    </datasources>
----////---
```

**Answer :**

Install the PostgreSQL driver and use the XML so that u can make it work.

Follow The Steps : (Suggested By `@Craig Ringer`) is Very HelpFull

[Download PgJDBC](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html). I'm assuming you're using postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar, the current version at time of writing. Adjust any filenames to match if you need a different version.

Now deploy the JDBC driver to JBoss AS 7 by putting it in the deployments folder or using the deploy command in jboss-cli. This will work for most, but not all, purposes.

Alternately, you an define a PostgreSQL JDBC driver module:

Create the path $JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/postgresql/main. The modules/org part should already exist, make directories for the rest.

In $JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/postgresql/main/modules.xml with the following content, changing the resource-root entry for the PgJDBC driver to refer to the driver you wish to use.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgresql">
         <resources>
             <resource-root path="postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar"/>
         </resources>
         <dependencies>
             <module name="javax.api"/>
             <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
             <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
         </dependencies>
     </module>

Into the same directory as modules.xml place postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar
Open jboss-cli by running $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli --connect
```

Run the command:

```
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgresql-driver:add(driver-name=postgresql-driver, driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver, driver-module-name=org.postgresql)
```

Now create any required data sources, etc, using postgresql-driver as the driver name.

You can create a datasource via the web ui, with jboss-cli with the data-source create command (see data-source --help, data-source add --help), or by deploying a -ds.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
  <datasource jndi-name="java:/datasources/PostgresqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true"  
        pool-name="PostgresqlDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql:dbname</connection-url>
    <driver>postgresql-driver</driver>
    <security>
      <user-name>username</user-name>
      <password>password</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>
</datasources>
```

For KitchenSink Example: I Tried With These, It Worked till Connection and All the Things.Still It Should be updated After Later...

[Follow this link](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/#optional_components) Till Creating a database and a user & continue the rest from here !
Change Persistance To :
**persitance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/KitchenQuickStartDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**test-persistance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/KitchensinkQuickstartTestDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**test-ds.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KitchenQuickStartTestDS"
        pool-name="KitchenQuickStartTestDS" enabled="true"
        use-java-context="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/QUICKSTART_DATABASENAME</connection-url>
        <driver>postgresql-driver</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>username</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
        </security>
   </datasource>
</datasources>
```

**kitchensink-quickstart-ds.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <!-- The datasource is bound into JNDI at this location. We reference 
        this in META-INF/persistence.xml -->
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KitchenQuickStartDS"
        pool-name="KitchenQuickStartDS" enabled="true"
        use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/QUICKSTART_DATABASENAME</connection-url>
        <driver>postgresql-driver</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>username</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

**But Where i'm Stuck is :**
I'm Unable to insert the Data Inot the Database! It is raising an error as

```
ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist Position: 17
```

I need A Help To Configure It .. I tried in [MANY ways](https://www.google.co.in/#q=ERROR%3A+relation+%22hibernate_sequence%22+does+not+exist+Position%3A+17+)

Comment: Do you have your JBoss running? Have you added the "PostgreSQL" datasource to your JBoss?

Comment: I have JBoss Running in my command prompt! by using standalone.bat,but i did not added the datasource!@fascynacja

Comment: [Configuring PostgreSQL to JBOSS](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/#optional_components),but i am stuck at JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --file=configure-postgresql.cli(STEP).. its opening a file jboss-cli.. How should i continue to fix it! @fascynacja

Comment: Even though i have configured the POSTGRESQL in the configuration its not working ! iHave edited the Question

Comment: another question is: What is the JBoss console output - which appears affter you run the maven command?

Comment: i didnt get any errors while i am using `mvn clean` and `mvn install` from my eclipse the build is done successfully,but while i am running from the directory path, `mvn clean package jboss-as:deploy` is raising an error as before..but in both cases i'm not getting the project to run..

Comment: can we go on further by Teamviewer! is there any wrong in doing so!

Comment: or else is there any repository or some blog like thing where i can get the solution of the solved kitchensink- woth postgresql @fascynacja Sorry to waste ur time! my hearty apologies to u!

Comment: I don't see anything in your example (nor in that example in question) which would require the use of the full profile. If you want to edit the server configuration change standalone.xml, not standalone-full.xml. Take a look at https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/blob/master/greeter/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/greeter-quickstart-ds.xml for an example (and placement) of a -ds.xml file

Comment: @LightGuard My problem is not with changing the standalone.xml file, i wanna make that kitchensink project run on basing PostgreSQL, so what r the necessary things i should to reach the goal..

Comment: If you already have a data source, modify the persistence.xml to use that data source and the correct hibernate dialect.

Comment: @user25616.. I ment to check the JBoss Console (one of the places where you can see LOGs of your app)- not your "CMD, Shell". You can also check the txt log file which you can find here: jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\server.log. Maybe there will be some information about exception which cause your app deploy to fail. There are many things which can cause it and its stupid to guess one after another:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if you still need help with this but I encounted similar error when deploying my application to the Openshift.

First I connected over SSH to openshift console. Then I ran `psql` (you can run psql on your host from `$POSTGRES_HOME/bin/psql`) with credentials for my postgres connection and used `\ds` and `\dt` to determine that hibernate_sequence was a table and not a sequence.

So I dropped it: `DROP TABLE hibernate_sequence;`

And recreated it as a sequence: `CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence;`

Comment: My Database:
`QUICKSTART_DATABASENAME-# \dt
       public | member | table | postgres                          & 
QUICKSTART_DATABASENAME-# \dl
      Large objects
 ID | Owner | Description
----+-------+-------------
(0 rows)`

Comment: it worked ! i had created a new Sequence and then rectified the errors raised slightly in conversion of string to long and type casting! Thank u

Answer (score 0):

For the Error Raised as: `ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist Position: 17`

i had created a `SEQUENCE` as Suggested by `@Martin Nuc`.

To Check Whether there is a Sequence in the Database or not use `\ds : Lists the Sequences` in the database.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence;
```

Then i had raised with few more errors like -> Type Cast like things then after Clearing those Errors It Worked ! Finally :-)

Thanks for the Support Every1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also add @Generator instead of being auto, you can add sequence and specify a sequence generator that is used by PostGre which is ${table_name}_${pk}_seq.

Nevertheless, One draw back of doing this is to making your app tightly coupled to sequences.

Another strategy is to make hibernate create that hibernate_sequence if you force it to create DDL.